# The latest best approach to determine the order of the system model

Tags: statistical-inference, mathematical-modeling, control-theory, signal-processing

The classical maximum likelihood estimation using [Akaike's criteria](http://bayes.acs.unt.edu:8083/BayesContent/class/Jon/MiscDocs/Akaike_1974.pdf) is defined by
$$\text{AIC}=-2\log^-\text{(maximum likelihood)} + 2 \text{(no. of independently adjusted parameters within the model)}$$

or mathematically,
$$\text{AIC}[p]=N\ln(\sigma^2)+2p$$
where $N$ is the number of sampling and $\sigma^2$ the variance of the model when the order is set to $p$.

This method was introduced last 1974 almost 50 years and it has been cited 58,000 times.

Is there a latest method which is widely used and has been applied to many applications?

Comment: Yes, there's BIC (also AICc and BICc). But I don't think newer methods have found footing in literature.  Just because something was established 50 years ago, it becomes irrelevant today. The entire field of machine learning was established a century ago for reference.